# Why getting a response from AWS DynamoDB through Lambda from my React app is very slow?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, axios, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am testing out the possibilities of Amazon AWS and DynamoDB, however, I can't find a solution as to why my Lambda function is executed with a delay.

I have set up a very simple test app with React and a simple table (less than 1kb) in DynamoDB. In react I have this call:

```
  async readTasks() {
    axios.get("https://13n6ump8q4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/serverlessToDoFunctionGET")
    .then(res => {
      let tasks = res.data.Items
      this.setState({
        tasklist:tasks,
      });
    });
  }
```

Which connects through AWS API Gateway to my Lambda serverlessToDoFunctionGET function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: "us-east-1"});
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    let scanningParameters = {
        TableName: "todo-app",
        Limit:20
    };

    docClient.scan(scanningParameters, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}
```

When I test the Lambda function from AWS Console it executes on average anywhere between 30-100ms (ignoring cold start values) which is great.

However, when I run it from my app (both locally and deployed) the average execution time is around 250ms! Lowest I got was still a whopping 220ms.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? To make me use of DynamoDB in my app I need to get below 100ms, otherwise it's just not worth it.

Things I've tried, but didn't have any effect:

- Increased Lambda function memory size from 128MB to 3008MB
- Double checked if the regions are everywhere the same
- Instead of using axios in React, I used fetch inside componentDidMount()

Comment: Why are you using the scan operation? Why not a query? If this is a primary access pattern, it should be a Query, not a scan. More than likely, either the schema on your base table is wrong or you need a GSI to query for this particular access pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try a query operation instead of scan. Even if it affects the speed slightly, I still don't understand why the Lambda function from AWS Lambda test panel executes well under 100ms but when called from client then it takes more than 200ms.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually testing for here? What is the network latency between your client and the server? If you want to calculate execution time on the Lambda and any roundtrips to DynamoDB, it needs to happen inside the function.

Comment: You are right, maybe I wasn't clear enough about what I am trying to achieve. 

I am trying to understand why the Lambda function executes so much faster when I test it in AWS Lambda (max 100ms) than when I call it from the client (min 220ms but on average 250ms and above), so I'm trying to understand how to reduce the network latency between my client and the server.